# Design of the home screen in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and having requirement to design my home screen for the app.which look like as shown below.

Home screen image.

[image]

as the picture shown above contain five button which having five different drawable image with different design and different size.the same layout while running in one device look different compare to the one running on other device.different device means here the different screen size and different resolution.so now the question is how to design that size and resolution of image and layout so its fit with any screen size and resolution on any device android device available in market and never expand or collapse with different screen size.i am testing the app in three different screen size device and resolution also and the look change for every device.Any kind of reply will be very helpful.

Comment: This topic is (imo) too complex to be answered here. Please take a look at the [android developers guide](http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html) regarding these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RelativeLayouts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) to separate the different boxes.

Apart from that, whatever you asked is broad.You should refer the **[Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)** documentation available at android.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the advice that's detailed in the documentation on how to design for different screen sizes. You're going to have to have more than one image to handle all your scenarios obviously.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

place Button background images in 4 resolutions in the res folder as ldpe mdpi hdpi and xhpdi .use Dip insted of dp.